# AWS CDK suddenly failing with Construct cannot be cast to class InterfaceVpcEndpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scala, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

As of yesterday my `cdk` code started returning an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class software.constructs.Construct cannot be cast to class software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint

This is being triggered by standard code that has not changed in months and has been deploying resources to AWS successfully:

```
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2._

val myVpc = Vpc.Builder...build()

myVpc.addInterfaceEndpoint(
  "SecretsManagerEndpoint",
  InterfaceVpcEndpointOptions
    .builder()
    .service(InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.SECRETS_MANAGER)
    .privateDnsEnabled(true)
    .build()
)
```

I've tried to revert the cdk npm package and reverting the `aws-cdk-lib` package that I'm pulling from maven, but neither fixed the issue.

**How can cdk be used to add an interface VPC endpoint without throwing a cast error?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related to `jsii` dependency:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76821623/1876739