# How to Override AWS CDK Resource Logical Id without causing cast Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

[This article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/override-logical-id-aws-cdk) provides instructions on overriding the logic id of a resource, and I have been using this technique successfully for months:

```
class MyConstruct(scope: Construct, id: String) extends Construct(scope, id) {
    val barFunc =
      lambda
        .Function
        .Builder
        .create(this, "bar")
        .handler("blah.blah")
        .code(lambda.Code.fromInline("blah"))
        .runtime(lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_10)
        .build

    barFunc
      .getNode
      .getDefaultChild
      .asInstanceOf[CfnFunction]
      .overrideLogicalId("mylogicalid")

}

class MyStack(scope: Construct, id: String, stackProps: StackProps) extends Stack(scope, id, stackProps) {
   val barConstruct = new MyConstruct(this, "bar")
}
```

Suddenly this code, which has not changed, is causing cdk to fail when executing `synth`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class software.constructs.Construct cannot be cast to class software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.CfnFunction

I think CDK made a breaking change.

**How can the logical id of a cdk resource be manually changed without causing a cast exception?**

I've tried reverting versions of cdk and the `aws-cdk-lib` with no success.

My current dependency set is:

[image]

This is based on the following dependencies:

```
  lazy val awsCdkLib = "software.amazon.awscdk" % "aws-cdk-lib" % "2.89.0"
  lazy val awsConstructs = "software.constructs" % "constructs" % "10.2.69"
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76818985/aws-cdk-suddenly-failing-with-construct-cannot-be-cast-to-class-interfacevpcendp) related to `InterfaceVpcEndpoint` which was resolved by using a separate method to create the endpoint.  In this case I am trying to update the logical id of an existing `Function` that can be successfully instantiated but not modified.

Comment: Seems like you have both CDK v1 and v2 installed and `CfnFunction` is from CDK v1.

Comment: @gshpychka Thank you for the suggestion, I ensured to clean my classpath and refined my dependencies to cdk `2.89`.  Still no luck.

Comment: List all the dependencies you have installed.

Comment: @gshpychka Question updated accordingly.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @gshpychka I don't understand, my question has the example that is failing.

Comment: The issue is not with the code. You would need to create a minimal reproducible example, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @gshpychka Fully reproducible example updated in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue today and found out this: https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/4202

Adding an exclusion for jsii and later explicitly declaring a downgraded version like below solved the issue for me.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-cdk-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-cdk-lib.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>software.amazon.jsii</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsii-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.jsii</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsii-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.85.0</version>
        </dependency>
```